# Ubuntu 18.04, cannot set LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: 18.04, java, environment-variables

In Ubuntu 16, I had set LD_LIBRARY_PATH via the file /etc/environment and it worked (guaranteed).

After the upgrade to 18.04 it does not.

I read various posts and the documentation regarding environment variables, and it appears that the way to do it is to create a file

```
/etc/ld.so.conf.d/xyc.conf
```

and add the lines there and then run

```
ldconfig
```

I did that, but

1. echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH gives an empty line
2. when I execute a simple java-Program with System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path")); the result is not what is in the files in the folder /etc/ld.so.conf.d. It seems that this mechanism is not working.

I don't understand this.

Comment: I don't think you can add environment variables to files in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` - just library paths themselves. What is the actual issue that you are trying to solve by setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: I need it for the gurobi optimizer.

Comment: I don't know what that is - however, rather than setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` globally, it's more usual to create a wrapper script for a particular application in which you set environment variables specific to that application, then call it. Setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` globally is likely to have unintended consequences for other programs.

Comment: I need the optimizer to work. I imagine the risk of consequences for other programs is rather low.